# Python concatenating string statement placed on separate lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-concatenation

Here is what I have tried and got the error:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5

if(1):
    get = str(a) +","       #Line 1
          +str(b) +","      #Line 2
          +str(c) +","      #Line 3
          +str(d) +","      #Line 4
          +str(e)       #Line 5
else:
    get = ",,,,,"
print(get)
```

Error:

```
  File "testingpython.py", line 8
    +str(b) +","      #Line 2
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Then I try to remove the spaces:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5

if(1):
    get = str(a) +","       #Line 1
+str(b) +","      #Line 2
+str(c) +","      #Line 3
+str(d) +","      #Line 4
+str(e)       #Line 5
else:
    get = ",,,,,"
print(get)
```

Error:

```
  File "testingpython.py", line 12
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Kindly, let me know how I can assign the string values to the variable when they are placed on separate lines.

Comment: There are simpler ways to [format a string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) like yours.

Comment: Code formatting is required, your code is ok.

Comment: Please do not take it as an offense. But you all sound a little dull to me. Try taking a look at my question please. I want the line separation with the comment included. Otherwise I would have asked any question related to it. Without knowing anything just start downvoting a question and feel proud you discourage someone.

Comment: Agreed, there is nothing wrong with this question, I have seen people use the backslash \ to spread their statements across lines and are unaware that brackets can also be used for splitting statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to wrap the lines inside parethesis to indicate that they belong together:

```
if(1):
    get = ( str(a) +","       #Line 1
          +str(b) +","      #Line 2
          +str(c) +","      #Line 3
          +str(d) +","      #Line 4
          +str(e)       #Line 5
    )
else:
    get = ",,,,,"
print(get)
```

But you could use a shorter method:

```
get = ','.join(str(s) for s in [a, b, c, d, e])
```

Comment: Thank you, your first suggestion helped me.

Answer (score 8):

In Python we generally use `\` symbol to break a single statement into multiple lines **iff** the statement is not inside parenthesis as:

```
result = "a" + "b" + "c"
```

can be reprsented as:

```
result = "a" + \
         "b" + \
         "c"
```

Or if the statement is with parenthesis then there is no need of `\` as:

```
result = ("a" + 
          "b" + 
          "c")
```